# Change in electric potential energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, charge, potential-energy

I am trying to find the velocity of a charged particle $+q$ as it moves away from a charged shell of charge $+Q$ to a distance of $2R$. I know I need to find the change in electric potential energy but I am confused of a stray minus sign.

This is what I have so far:

$$\Delta U =U_f-U_i=KqQ[\frac{1}{2R}-\frac{1}{R}]=-\frac{KqQ}{2R}$$

So the change in potential energy is negative. However in the answer sheet it states that the change in potential energy is positive. I am not sure what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Should I be using the formula for potential rather than potential energy?

Comment: I have removed my comment ---- Yes you are fine to use potential energy other than potential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no comment on your answer sheet; however, consider this: two positively charged particles left alone would move away from each other naturally. In terms of potential energy this is possible if the system moves from a position with higher potential to a new position with lower potential energy, gaining kinetic energy in the process. The difference between final and initial energies is therefore negative.